# how to assign a search result with __iexact to a foreignkey value django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to assign a search result with __iexact to a foreign key value

```
class ListInfo(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name= models.ForeignKey(NameList,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    #others


class NameList(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    #others
```

I want to create an object from `ListInfo`, with default `name` which assigned to the search name result! and this is my views.py

```
def addNewNameInfo(request):
    qs = NameList.objects.values_list('name',flat=True)
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    name_info = NameList.objects.filter(name__iexact=name)
    add_new_name_info =ListInfoForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        add_new_name_info = ListInfoForm(request.POST)
        if add_new_name_info .is_valid():
            obj = add_new_name_info .save(commit=False)
            obj.admin = request.user
            obj.name= name_info.name # i also tried this : obj.name= request.GET.get('name')
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request,'created')
    return render(request,'myfolder/my_template.html',{'names':qs,'name_info':name_info,'add_new_name_info':add_new_name_info })
```

and this is my template

```html
<form method='GET'>
   <select name="name" class="form-control" id="type">
      <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">names</option>
        {% for value in names %}
      <option  value="{{value}}">{{ value }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
     </select>
   <button type="submit">search</button>
 </form>
 <!--then -->
   {% if name_info%}
     {% for i in name_info%}
      <!--return some information about the selected name -->
     {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  
    {% if name_info%}
       <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
          {{add_new_name_info.errors}}
          <ul>
             {{add_new_name_info.as_p}}
          </ul>
          <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
    {% endif %}
```

but it raise th

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'

while I have the name in my `NameList`? can we do something like that to assign a value from GET request to a foreign key value? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line
 `name_info = NameList.objects.filter(name__iexact=name)`

your are not fetching a specific item, you retrieve a queryset (which is an iterable, django uses to wrap DB query that is executed when called).

because it's an iterable of NameList objects, you can't access a `.name` attribute, you need to either iterate over each one of the NameList objects returned by the queryset, or change your DB query to use `NameList.objects.get()` which returns a single NameList object (or throws a NameList.DoesNotExist exception if it cannot find the one you need)

You can read more about django QuerySet APIs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/